# Module or tool for web-based data import and ETL?

Tags: web-applications, etl, data-import

I'm going to be adding a feature to a web application that allows users to import data.  I don't want to reinvent wheel, so I am looking for any module I could integrate that would handle this.

The interface should be similar to that of importing a file into Excel or Access plus some more complex mapping and type conversion functions typically found in ETL software.

General Flow:

1. Upload a file (CVS, Excel, etc.)
2. Preview the data in the file -- use the first row as column names and then show the first N records so the user can verify the file was parsed properly
3. Show a mapping interface to select how the source columns match to the destination
4. Process the import and validate the data
5. Provide report of data that failed import with option to download a file of just the failed rows

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a single module out there, but here are some pretty cool tools to accomplish at least parts of this:

1. [File Uploading](http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/)
2. [CSV Parsing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Other than this, [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) offers is one of the best web-based Database managers (for MySQL databases).